# Delete lines matching pattern in file1 and save these deleted lines to file2

Tags: text-processing, sed

I have `file1`, and I need to delete lines matching a pattern. But I would like to save these deleted lines in another `file2`.

```
sed    '/zz/!d' file1 > file2
sed -i '/zz/d' file1
```

Is there a way to combine these commands into one ?

Or is there a more elegant way to do it?

Comment: I would replace the first `sed` invocation with a `grep`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Checked at GNU Sed:

```
sed -ni '/zz/!{p;b};w file2' file1
```

The flags must go in that order `-ni`.

Explanation:
We do not stop the script with the `d` command, but set the `-n` flag (silent) and write lines that do not match the template using the `p` command (Print the current pattern space) and jump with `b` to the end of the script. Lines matching the pattern reach the `w` command, which writes the pattern space to the file.

Comment: @nezabudka - that is beautiful. How do I reverse the match though. I actually need the reverse action: when line does not match zz then delete it from file1, and  print to file2.

Comment: @400theCat, remove the exclamation mark `!`

Comment: last thing: I need to append to file2, not overwrite. Is it possible ?

Comment: @Quasímodo - no, it does not have to be `sed`. I accepted @nezabudka because I like the simplicity of his `sed` solution. But please do provide your `awk` solution, if you have an idea.

Answer (score 8):

```
perl -pi -e 'select( /zz/ ? STDOUT : ARGVOUT )' file1 > file2
```

`-i` handles in-place editing of file1. `-p` prints lines after running the perl program. All the program needs to do is select where the output goes. In this case, that be achieved using `?:` to choose either the standard output, or `ARGVOUT` (which is what `-i` uses).

Comment: I love this. Blindingly obvious in retrospect, but I had never thought of using `select()` with `-p` like this before. I'm going to be stealing this! >:)

Answer (score 5):

With any Awk:

```
awk '/zz/{print >> "file2"; next} 1' file1 > tmp && mv tmp file1
```

If you don't like explicitly creating a temporary file, with **GNU Awk**:

```
gawk -i inplace '/zz/{print >> "file2"; next} 1' file1
```

Change `>>` to `>` if you want to truncate `file2` instead of appending to it.

See also: [Why does "1" in awk print the current line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20262869/why-does-1-in-awk-print-the-current-line)

Comment: how can I reverse the match? ie, if line matches `zz`, it should stay in file1. if not match, it should go to file2.

Comment: how can I use variable instead of "file2"? The following does not work because `$F` is inside single quotes: `gawk -i inplace '!/^: 1:0;/{print >> "$F"; next} 1' file1`. But when I change the single quotes to double quotes, the `gawk` construct does not work anymore. Thank you.

Comment: @400theCat unlike some other tools, there's no apparently magical incantations in awk scripts, it's just plain Algol-like syntax just like C, Ada, pascal, etc. etc. and you just write it to do what you want it to do. I'm sure you can understand the existing scripts and at least try to tweak the logic to do whatever else you want. Try it, you'll probably get it right almost immediately. For using a variable, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075671/how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script.

Answer (score 4):

Another way, using `ed`:

```
# Delete file2 if it already exists first.
ed -s file1 <<'EOF'
g/zz/.W file2\
d
w
EOF
```

Ever line matching the basic regular expression `zz` is first appended to `file2`, and then deleted. Finally the modified `file1` is saved.

Comment: Note `W` is not POSIX, in contrast to `w`. If you use Ex instead, `w!>>file2` is POSIX.

Answer (score 3):

Just use `perl` with the `-i` flag instead and have it print matching lines to stdout so you can redirect them to a file:

```
$ cat file1
asdasd
baba zzbabab
asdasd
sadkzzpasdad

$ perl -i -ne 'if(/zz/){ print STDOUT } else{ print }' file1 > file2

You could rewrite the above via a string form of eval where we construct
 the above piece of perl code based on presence of zz:

$ perl -i -ne 'eval "print ".qw[STDOUT][!/zz/]' file1 > file2

$ cat file1
asdasd
asdasd

$ cat file2 
baba zzbabab
sadkzzpasdad
```

---

Another way in perl can be:

```
$ perl -pi -e 'print(STDOUT),s/.*//s if /zz/' file1 > file2
```

- use the autoprint mode `-p`
- print into stdout the zz lines then null them when they will be written back onto file1 via the `-i` mode.

Comment: @guest_7 I am used to writing `print STDOUT "foo\n"`. Is there any benefit/advantage in using `print(STDOUT),"foo"` or is it just classic perl TIMTOWTDI? Just curious, and you seem to know your Perl.

Comment: print(STDOUT),"foo\n" are two statements. First is print printing onto the stdout the default var $_. Second is the string "foo\n" just there. It has NO relation to the print.

Comment: Ah! Of course! I see now, the comma allows you to use the trailing `if` on both statements, like doing `if(/zz/){print; s///}`, Gotcha. But is there any difference between `print STDOUT` and `print(STDOUT)` or is it just a question of stylistic preference?

Comment: In this specific case the brackets are necessary lest print will think STDOUT is the first argument to be printed and s/.*//s is the second argument (it's return value in a list context actually) to be printed. With brackets it implies that $_ ( current line) is printed on stdout and the s/.*//s is there to null the current line so that when it gets printed in the file1 ir should Not show up, essentially deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a silly pipe oriented method using GNU `grep`, along with the [`sponge` util](https://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/) for convenience:

```
grep 'zz'      file1 | tee  file2 | 
grep -vf -     file1 | sponge file1
```

Or without `tee`, and one less pipe:

```
grep 'zz'      file1 > file2 
grep -vf file2 file1 | sponge file1
```

Answer (score -1):

```
awk '/zz/' file1 >file2 && awk '!/zz/' file1 >file3 && mv file3 file1
```

Comment: Any time you find yourself calling multiple awk scripts on the same input you can be sure you have the wrong approach.